# How to delete a particular row in a dynamically created html rows using Javascript DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Here am trying to add a html rows by clicking on the add button and delete the added rows on clicking on the delete button.

Its working fine with adding rows as expected. But the problem is the delete function deletes the last row of the table instead of deleting that corresponding row.

As there is delete button in every row, only that corresponding row should be deleted when the delete button is clicked.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nKkhW/3/) which demonstrates the situation better.

if the fiddle above failed to load as it does, Please refer the code below.

Thanks in advance

### JAVSCRIPT

```
//function to add a row 
function insSpec()
    {


    rl=document.getElementById("insSpecc").rows.length;
    var a=document.getElementById("insSpecc").insertRow(rl);
    var h=a.insertCell(0);
    var f=a.insertCell(1);
    var m=a.insertCell(2);
    var n=a.insertCell(3);
    h.innerHTML='<div class="separator"><input type="text" name="client_prod[]"  class="separator" id="competitor_prod'+rl+'" style="width:150px"  >';
    f.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="client_nrx[]" id="client_nrx'+rl+'" size="5"  />';
    m.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="client_rrx[]"  id="client_rrx'+rl+'" size="5"  />';
    n.innerHTML='<button   class="del_img" onClick="delSpec('+rl+')">Delete</button></div>';

    }
//function to delete a row
function delSpec(rl)
    {   
    r=document.getElementById("insSpecc").rows.length;
    if(r!=2)
    {
        document.getElementById("insSpecc").deleteRow(r-1)
    }


    }
```

### HTML

```
<table id="insSpecc" width="100%;">
    <div class="separator">
    <tr>
        <td><span>Product</span></td>
        <td><span>NRX(Qty)</span></td>
        <td><span>RRX(Qty)</span></td></tr></div>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="client_prod" name="client_prod[]" style="width:150px;" class="validate[required] text-input"></td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" id="client_nrx" name="client_nrx[]" size="5" class="validate[required] text-input">

        </td>
            <td>
        <input type="text" id="client_rrx" name="client_rrx[]" size="5">

        </td>
          <td>
        <button id="add_img"   id='insSpecimg' style='display:block;' onClick="insSpec()" align="center">Add</button>
        </td>   
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Not the problem, but you shouldn't have a `<div>` element as the first thing inside a `<table>` element. The browser might be nice enough to handle it for you, but really it is invalid html. Also, always use `var`, unless you specifically intended `delSpec()`'s `r` variable and `insSpec()`'s `rl` variable to be global.

Comment: Your table is missing a `<tbody>` tag. That might help you understand the DOM better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
 n.innerHTML='<button   class="del_img" onClick="delSpec(this)">Delete</button></div>';
```

and later

```
function delSpec(node)
    {    
    r=node.parentNode.parentNode;
    r.parentNode.removeChild(r);
    }
```

in such case delSpec will receive pointer to the button, and will be able to delete the necessary row.

Comment: Thanks alot :) it solved my problem efficiently.Hopefully it sustains :) +1

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById("insSpecc").deleteRow(r-1)`

which should be

`document.getElementById("insSpecc").deleteRow(rl);`

Comment: This is right method. There's no need to bloat markup when a nice API already exists.

Answer (score 1):

You should use id for each row, and u can delete that row with the ID... There are several ways to get a DOM element object in jQuery and other libraries.

All you need to do is, use getElementById("the id of the row") and store that element in a variable, or make it's innerHTML=""; or delete it like xdazz suggested.

You can also get elements with class names... so, if your row is using any css class, you can get that row like you did with the ID.

Aquatic is also right: you either need to access all the DOM, traverse it, and reach ur desired element and do whatever with it, or access it with element's id or class name.

You can also change ur html markup for each row to have a check box which tells which rows to delete... and for each row if a checkbox is selected, delete the row.

Vote up if you got the point.

Comment: You don't need an `id` for each row. In fact, I wouldn't recommend any of your solutions.